# How to Append Dash to Existing String?

Tags: python, string, loops, full-text-indexing

For a homework problem, one of my functions requires a dash to be added at a certain index.  For instance, with a sequence such as "ABC" - at index 2 of a new string (as per Python rules) - the string would ideally output "AB-C."  So, index 2 of a new string.

(code provided) I attempted to set aside any part of the phrase before where the dash would be placed, and played around with trying to add the dash at index 2 with my 2nd line.
 I know I need a new string, but I am otherwise confused about how to create a new string and be able to place the dash at the desired index.

```py
def insert_indel(sequence, index):

    head = sequence[:index]
    tail = sequence[ index+1: ]
    return head + '-' + tail

v = insert_indel('ABC', 1)
print(v)
```

I only am outputting "A-G" - it is substituting a dash at the 2nd index of the old string instead of putting it onto a new string.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
def insert_indel(sequence, index):

    head = sequence[:index]
    tail = sequence[ index: ]
    return head + '-' + tail

v = insert_indel('ABC', 2)
print(v)
```

Input: ABC 2

Output: AB-C